# What is a team distributor according to Apple's Provisioning documentation?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning

I am a team admin and I am trying to get Xcode to request and download a distribution (not development) certificate. However it appears to need to be a 'team distributor' in order to do this according to Apple documentation.

```
If you are the team distributor, Xcode requests and downloads your team’s distribution certificate, in addition to downloading your development certificate.
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/obtain_certificates_and_provisioning_profiles.html

I can't find team distributor anywhere else in the documentation. Can a team admin download a development certificate through Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

There are only three roles within the Provisioning Portal, as defined [by the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html).

Team Member, Team Admin and Team Agent. Agent is higher than Admin, but the only extra privilege is being able to accept legal documentation. As such, any Team Admin is able to download + create development or distribution certificates, or accept requests from any Team Members.

> Team members can request development certificates and download development provisioning profiles.